# Kernel panic on a new MBP 2017 Touch bar (virtual box suspected)

Tags: macos, high-sierra, virtualbox

2 weeks into a new MBP touch bar 2017 and i get a kernel panic:

can someone read the log and tell me what's up?

thanks in advance.

```
Anonymous UUID:       6B3D5FAD-A7B2-9D30-CB2B-15E5EC8E6296

Wed Jan 17 14:41:02 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff80138a4286): "memRefEntry"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.31.3/iokit/Kernel/IOMemoryDescriptor.cpp:3158
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9242cf32c0 : 0xffffff80132505f6 
0xffffff9242cf3310 : 0xffffff801337d604 
0xffffff9242cf3350 : 0xffffff801336f0f9 
0xffffff9242cf33d0 : 0xffffff8013202120 
0xffffff9242cf33f0 : 0xffffff801325002c 
0xffffff9242cf3520 : 0xffffff801324fdac 
0xffffff9242cf3580 : 0xffffff80138a4286 
0xffffff9242cf36a0 : 0xffffff80138a20ba 
0xffffff9242cf36d0 : 0xffffff80138a7827 
0xffffff9242cf3710 : 0xffffff7f95afab16 
0xffffff9242cf3750 : 0xffffff7f96dd6317 
0xffffff9242cf3780 : 0xffffff7f95aba629 
0xffffff9242cf37a0 : 0xffffff7f95af8dfd 
0xffffff9242cf37c0 : 0xffffff7f95ad2b76 
0xffffff9242cf3800 : 0xffffff7f95ac1bdc 
0xffffff9242cf3850 : 0xffffff7f96df55c0 
0xffffff9242cf3890 : 0xffffff7f96def34c 
0xffffff9242cf3940 : 0xffffff7f95ac0911 
0xffffff9242cf3980 : 0xffffff7f95ac0e23 
0xffffff9242cf39b0 : 0xffffff7f95ac7228 
0xffffff9242cf39f0 : 0xffffff7f96df4c3f 
0xffffff9242cf3a30 : 0xffffff7f95abe9ae 
0xffffff9242cf3ac0 : 0xffffff80138bb009 
0xffffff9242cf3b20 : 0xffffff80138b91a0 
0xffffff9242cf3b70 : 0xffffff80138c1e47 
0xffffff9242cf3cb0 : 0xffffff8013329844 
0xffffff9242cf3dc0 : 0xffffff8013255c30 
0xffffff9242cf3e10 : 0xffffff8013232cbd 
0xffffff9242cf3e60 : 0xffffff8013245b7b 
0xffffff9242cf3ef0 : 0xffffff801335952d 
0xffffff9242cf3fa0 : 0xffffff8013202926 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(376.6)[5F8F39B4-41AB-3263-9867-D0FAF9BBD2AE]@0xffffff7f95ab9000->0xffffff7f95b4efff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[58669FC2-CC90-3594-AD69-DB89B923FD20]@0xffffff7f941fb000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(209.2.2)[AE58720D-7079-388F-AD95-FD2366F98F8D]@0xffffff7f95a9d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C08F7FC1-78A4-3A1B-BFE2-C07080CF2048]@0xffffff7f93a94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(517.22)[2AEA02BF-2A38-3674-A187-E5F610FD65B7]@0xffffff7f94235000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics(10.3)[E5B52185-2A01-3DB9-A5F6-C6A030153395]@0xffffff7f96d9e000->0xffffff7f96e90fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(209.2.2)[AE58720D-7079-388F-AD95-FD2366F98F8D]@0xffffff7f95a9d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C08F7FC1-78A4-3A1B-BFE2-C07080CF2048]@0xffffff7f93a94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(517.22)[2AEA02BF-2A38-3674-A187-E5F610FD65B7]@0xffffff7f94235000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(376.6)[5F8F39B4-41AB-3263-9867-D0FAF9BBD2AE]@0xffffff7f95ab9000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He

Mac OS version:
17C205

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0: Thu Nov  9 18:09:22 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.31.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 87641697-A3DD-30C4-B010-E65ECE57550B
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8013000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012f00000
System model name: MacBookPro14,3 (Mac-551B86E5744E2388)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 17052153372557
last loaded kext at 13434751155685: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9c0c3000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 13675010961608: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9c0b7000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.2.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.2.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.2.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.2.4
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.24
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   280.12
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.16.21
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.16.2
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4150   1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.kext.AMD9515Controller    1.6.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics  10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.16.21
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.31.8
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.30.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 127
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1220.28.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.IOBufferCopyEngineTest    1
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 280.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.16.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.16.21
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   517.22
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.16.21
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    376.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    517.22
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   209.2.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    1204.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   203
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 127
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1204.13
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1201.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    52
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  52
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBufferCopyEngineFamily    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    650.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCRTC    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Did a bit of digging and found a Technical Note on Kernel Panics: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2063/_index.html

I've skimmed over it and it looks good. The `Isolating the Crash`
 section will be of most help in this case, as well as: `How to Read the Panic Log from an Intel-Based Mac` as knowing how to read the log will help you debug it.